# Oracle AQ using JMS and JMSXGroupID does not result in 'sticky' consumers

Tags: oracle, jms, message-queue, activemq-artemis

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis uses `JMSXGroupId` to implement 'sticky' consumer sessions. Messages enqueued with the same `JMSXGroupId` are sent to the same consumer, in FIFO, single threaded. This does however allow for multiple threads to process unique `JMSXGroupId` groups concurrently - which is perfect - see below:

```
16:46:42.451 [Thread-4] INFO Log - This is Message 30 In JMSXGroup: Group C | To Thread Thread-4
16:46:42.451 [Thread-3] INFO Log - This is Message 283 In JMSXGroup: Group B | To Thread Thread-3
16:46:42.451 [Thread-3] INFO Log - This is Message 284 In JMSXGroup: Group B | To Thread Thread-3
16:46:42.451 [Thread-4] INFO Log - This is Message 31 In JMSXGroup: Group C | To Thread Thread-4
16:46:42.452 [Thread-4] INFO Log - This is Message 32 In JMSXGroup: Group C | To Thread Thread-4
16:46:42.452 [Thread-3] INFO Log - This is Message 285 In JMSXGroup: Group B | To Thread Thread-3
```

Oracle AQ and Amazon SQS do not exhibit the same 'sticky' consumer behaviour. I cannot find anything specific in the JMS Specification other than `JMSXGroupId` is used to group related messages together.

My expectation was that all JMS Consumers would exhibit this 'sticky' behaviour when `JMSXGroupId` was set but this does not appear to be the case.

Has anyone managed to achieve this behaviour with Oracle AQ / SQS solely by setting JMSXGroupId? Or is the intention of `JMSXGroupId` to allow the `consumer` to use a `selector` when dequeuing? That does not seem as though it would scale as it would need to be discerned at runtime, whereas the ActiveMQ implementation clearly does.

Comment: /features/standard/queue-selector/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/QueueSelectorExample.java

// Step 8. Prepare two selectors
         String redSelector = "color='red'";
         String greenSelector = "color='green'";

         // Step 9. Create a JMS Message Consumer that receives 'red' messages
         Session redSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         MessageConsumer redConsumer = redSession.createConsumer(queue, redSelector);
         redConsumer.setMessageListener(new SimpleMessageListener("red", result));

Comment: So the `queue-selector` example shipped with the broker is an example of using selectors to receive messages. However, this has nothing to do with message grouping.

Comment: I took another look and figured that was just an example of using a selector to receive a message as opposed to having anything to do with grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JMS specification only states that messages in the same group should be consumed in order. It doesn't say *how* this functionality should be implemented.

ActiveMQ Artemis implements message grouping by dispatching all the messages in the same group to a single consumer (i.e. what you call "sticky" consumers). However, other JMS providers are free to implement this functionality in other ways.

As noted previously, the only requirement is that messages in the same group are consumed in order. If you've tested this functionality on Oracle AQ and Amazon SQS and have evidence that the messages in the same group are *not* consumed in order then you should contact those providers for support. It is not valid to simply say that their implementations are different from ActiveMQ Artemis if the ultimate result is the same.

Comment: I’ve yet to see messages in the same JMSXGroup being processed in order with either AQ or SQS. I’m going to continue investigating but following the same steps that I did with Artemis is leading to different behaviour in AQ and SQS. 

Thanks Justin for taking the time to reply, invaluable insightful information. Due to my rep I can’t upvote but I’ve marked your reply as the answer.